# Interviewing a Single User About an Existing UI Improvements

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, interview

I am about to interview / ask questions from a single end-user, who has been using the application in prod for 3 months daily.

I am wondering is there some existing question set to begin this with? I would like to start with some existing question set and add some of my custom questions.

Topics that I'm interested in are as follows:

- The usability problems of the current implementation
- Possible alternative solutions (more radical approach to the actual problem)

So, I'm trying to confirm if the current UI design is valid --- or does it need a major remake. If so, what kind of?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One person's feedback will not be determinative, because this user can be an outlier. Depending on the complexity of the application you might need at least 5 people to uncover most problems. That said starting with recalling the last experience might be a good starting point. Something like, tell us about the last time you used this application/performed this task. How was your experience like?